# Calculate Min Mean Max For Rows Where Multiple Columns Have Same Values

Tags: r, dataframe

In the below data set I want to first check which rows have same value for both column `U` and `T`. For all such rows I want to calculate mean of `Mean` column, min of `Min` column and max of `Max` column.

I can do this easily if the rows with same value of column `U` and `T` are separate `data.frame()`, but for this case I first need to extract all such sub `data.frame()` with in `data.frame()` and then perform the operation.

If anyone has a better approach using `R` libraries please suggest?

**Input Data**

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA
), C = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Yes", class = "factor"), 
    U = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), T = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), P = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "INT", class = "factor"), Q = 1:4, R = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), S = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), W = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), Mean = c(21.208, 
    21.22333333, 21.23666667, 21.174), Min = c(21.02, 21.01, 
    21.09, 21.02), Max = c(21.35, 21.39, 21.47, 21.36)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

**Expected Output**

```
A   B   C   U   T   P   Q   R   S   T   Mean    Min     Max
0.1 NA  Yes 11  A   INT 4   0   1   A   21.2105 21.01   21.47
```

Comment: How did you end up with this dataset?

Comment: .@akrun -The output I showed is basically first calculating mean of `Mean` column, then min of `Min` column and then max of `Max` column. It's like three way parametric calculation on three different rows. I obviously used excel to show the expected output.

Comment: It looks interesting

Comment: .@akrun - It's challenging and it's interesting for you, for sure I never could have written `R` code for this :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  group_by(U, T) %>%
  mutate(Mean = mean(Mean), Min = min(Min), Max = max(Max))%>% 
  slice(1)
```

Comment: .@akrun - Thank you. But `vars(A:P)` is specific to the data set above, how can I make it dynamic?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  In your description, it says `U, T` are the columns

Comment: .@akrun - No. In question I mentioned the main key is column `U` and `T` which should be used to group the rows.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Okay, I changed the code to have grouping columns as U, T while getting the mean, min and max from the other column in `mutate` step

Comment: .@akrun - Can you explain use of `slice(1)`?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  After we create the columns 'Mean', 'Min', 'Max' for each group 'U', 'T', `slice` the first row, ie. `slice` takes an index and gets the row of that index of each group.  Here ,it is the first row

Answer (score 1):

```
nm = names(data)[!names(data) %in% c("Mean", "Min", "Max")]
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, paste(data$U, data$T)), function(x){
    data.frame(x[1, nm], Mean = mean(x$Mean), Min = min(x$Min), Max = max(x$Max))
}))
#       A  B   C  U T   P Q R S W    Mean   Min   Max
#11 A 0.1 NA Yes 11 A INT 1 0 1 A 21.2105 21.01 21.47
```

Comment: .@d.b - Thank you. Is `x[1,1:10]` not dynamic? Can I use `x[1,1:ncol(data)]`?